# Directional derivative in direction of unit tangent vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, curves

Find the derivative of $$f(x,y)= x^2 + y^2$$ in the direction of the unit tangent vector of curve $$r(t) = (cos(t)+tsin(t))i + (sin(t)-cos(t))j$$

gradient of f is $$2xi+2yj$$

$$d/dt  ((cos(t)+tsin(t)) = tcost$$
$$d/dt((sin(t)-cos(t)) = tsint$$
norm of u = $$\sqrt{((tcost)^2)+((tsint)^2))}$$
$$=\sqrt{(t^2cos^2t+t^2sin^2t)}$$
$$=\sqrt{(t^2(cos^2t+sin^2t))}$$
$$=\sqrt{(t^2(1))=sqrt(t^2)}$$
$$=t$$

u = dr/dt = $$\frac{(tcosti+tsintj)}{(\sqrt{((tcost)^2)+((tsint)^2))})}$$

$$= costi+sintj$$

grad * u = ?

Correct answer is 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax command are not effective unless they are surrounded by `$` signs.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Your issue is that you started with a mistake in the formula for the tangent to the curve. There should not be a $t$ factor in front of $\sin$. And use `$\sin t$`, to be more legible.